# Android add separate google map api key for release and debug build modes

Tags: android, google-maps

i am developing an android application using android studio 2.3. I added google map activity to my project using built in add activity dialog.

When i check the google map api key it is saved in a separate xml file inside values folder but under debug varient. I need to add a new api key that is going to use only for relase mode (builds). How do i add such a separate api key xml file for release mode as well?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create same xml file in `release` folder.

You're default debug key is probably in file `project_location/src/debug/res/values/some_file_name.xml`.

You need to create same file in `project_location/src/release/res/values/some_file_name.xml` And put you'r release key there.

Answer (score 3):

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key"/>
```

app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR DEBUG KEY]"
        }
        release {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "[YOUR RELEASE KEY]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the debug and\or release folder structure in the same folder as your "main" one.  Any files placed here will replace the ones in main depending on the build type.

[image]